# I am using Zookeeper and Kafka, But After creating the first topic, topic name is not visible in the list

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am using below Commands.

I started the Zookeeper Using This

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Then I started Kafka

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Then I create my first topic using this

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

For List of Topics i wrote.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

But Screen is empty without any error. I followed [this guide](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart).

When i open /tmp/kafka-logs/ which file need to see here.

`devpreet@197nodnb23196:/tmp/kafka-logs/test-0$ cd /tmp/kafka-logs
devpreet@197nodnb23196:/tmp/kafka-logs$ ls -lrt
total 220
-rw-r--r-- 1 devpreet devpreet    0 Mar 11 14:34 cleaner-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 devpreet devpreet   54 Mar 11 14:34 meta.properties
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-5
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 test-0
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-0
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-29
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-48
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-10
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-45
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-26
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-7
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-42
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-4
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-23
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-1
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-20
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-39
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-17
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-36
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-14
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-33
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-49
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-11
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-30
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-46
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-27
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-8
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-24
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-43
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-21
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-2
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-40
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-37
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-18
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-34
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-15
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-12
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-31
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-9
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-47
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-19
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-28
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:19 __consumer_offsets-38
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:20 __consumer_offsets-35
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:20 __consumer_offsets-44
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:20 __consumer_offsets-6
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:20 __consumer_offsets-25
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:20 __consumer_offsets-16
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:20 __consumer_offsets-22
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:20 __consumer_offsets-41
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:20 __consumer_offsets-32
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:20 __consumer_offsets-3
drwxr-xr-x 2 devpreet devpreet 4096 Mar 12 23:20 __consumer_offsets-13
-rw-r--r-- 1 devpreet devpreet 1204 Mar 13 10:43 replication-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 devpreet devpreet 1204 Mar 13 10:43 recovery-point-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 devpreet devpreet    4 Mar 13 10:43 log-start-offset-checkpoint`

Comment: Are there are any errors in Zookeeper or Broker logs?

Comment: Default log locations for kafka are under - "/tmp/kafka-logs". Can you search for errors or add log details with your question?

Comment: @VarunBajaj When i went to /tmp/kafka-logs/ there is lot of files there please check.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please run following commands after starting Broker and Zookeeper services and check -

```
varun@abc.com$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
>test
[2019-03-13 06:35:12,915] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {test=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
^C

varun@abc.com$ kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning --property print.key=true --property print.value=true
null    test
^CProcessed a total of 1 messages
```

Comment: Thanks It resolved actually the problem was i installed two version of zookeper. One from direct downlaod and second from apt get. Now its fine. Thanks  :)